# Add Items to Combobox Dynamically

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a WPF `Listview` with Item Details such as Item Name and Description.

I also have a `ComboBox` that contains values (1-10) which are added dynamically (using code-behind).

I'm trying to get the correct "Item Name" from the `ListView` based on the currently selected `ComboBox` value, but I don't know how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a converter:

```
public class SelectRangeFromCollectionConverter<T> : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        IEnumerable<T> coll = value as IEnumerable<T>;
        if (coll != null) {
            int index;
            if (parameter != null && 
                int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out index) &&
                index > 0) {
                List<T> newColl = new List<T>();
                foreach (T item in coll) {
                    if(index==0) return newColl;
                    newColl.Add(item);
                    index--;
                }
                //not enough items
                return newColl;
            }
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

```
<youNameSpace:SelectRangeFromCollectionConverter x:TypeArguments="TheTypeOfYourData" x:Key="SelectRangeFromCollectionConverter"/> 

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection, Converter={StaticResource SelectRangeFromCollectionConverter}, ConverterParameter=10}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YouType}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```